# How to compare a datetime without removing the time IN SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How can I compare 2 datetime values in SQL Server without removing the time? I have only found answers in which they assign the hours, minutes and seconds to 0 but for the process I am carrying out it is important to also compare the hours.

For example I have the following 2 dates, `2020-02-07 12:14:39.997` and `2020-02-06 10:20:51.237`. When trying to compare if the first date is less than the second, it is true that the first date is less than the second, which is incorrect.

Comment: Why are your datetimes in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh: mi: ss.mmm` (note the spaces after `hi` and `mi`)? That means that they are being stored as a `varchar`. First fix the design, then worrying about the comparison.

Comment: They are saved in ODBC canonical (with milliseconds) default for time, date, datetime2, and datetimeoffset

Comment: Date and time data types don't have a format, @pete , they are binary values. By therefore stating *"the format I use is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm (24h)"* you are starting "I am not use a Date and time data type to store by dates and times." The default **display format** in applications like SSMS is `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`, there is not space after the hours and minutes.

Comment: @pete For clarification, what is the data type of the column in the database?

Comment: @Larnu is datetime

Comment: Please show the code that you are using that tells you the first datetime value is less than the second.

Comment: *it is true that the first date is less than the second* how do you get this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare both the dates as shown below.

```
declare @firstDate datetime= '2020-02-07 12: 14: 39.997'
declare @secondDate datetime = '2020-02-06 10: 20: 51.237'

if(@firstDate > @secondDate)
begin
    Select 'First date is greater' as [Decision]
end
else
begin
    Select 'Second date is greater' as [Decision]
end
```